# How to assign value from select option elements to another div childs

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

I am trying to make a gallery which shows pictures according to some criteria like : 1- style, 2 -year and 3- size.

I have made a `<select>` with a few options for each criteria as you can see below :

```
<div id="SearchBar">
    You can filter the pictures according to the following options:<br><br>

  <label for="Estilo">Estilo:</label><br>

    <select name="Estilo" id="Estilo">
      <option value="vazio" >-</option>
      <option value="Pintura a óleo" >Pintura a óleo</option>
      <option value="Retrato">Retrato</option>
      <option value="Lápis" selected>Lápis</option>
      <option value="Aguarela">Aguarela</option>
      <option value="Ilustrações">Ilustrações</option>

    </select><br><hr>

  <label for="Ano">Ano:</label><br> 

    <select name="Ano" id="Ano">
      <option value="null">-</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2010">2010</option>
      <option value="2009">2009</option>
      <option value="2008">2008</option>
      <option value="2007">2007</option>
      <option value="2006">2006</option>
      <option value="2005">2005</option>
      <option value="2004">2004</option>
      <option value="2003">2003</option>
      <option value="2002">2002</option>
      <option value="2001">2001</option>
      <option value="2000">2000</option>
      <option value="1999">1999</option>
    </select><br><hr>

    <label for="Dimensões">Dimensões:</label><br>

    <select name="Dimensões" id="Dimensões">
      <option value="null">-</option>
      <option value="pequeno">10*15 a 35*40</option>
      <option value="medio">35*40 a 50*50</option>
      <option value="grande">50*50 a 80*90</option>
      <option value="XXL">80*90 a 100*120</option>
    </select><br><hr><br>

    <button>Search</button> <button>Reset</button>
 </div>
```

Now , in another div I have the actual photos, if you want to see, here it is :

```
  <div id ="CaixaGaleria" class="gallery">
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200728_064349.jpg" class="Pintura a óleo" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200727_224457.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233940.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/quadra-mar.260x300.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Filme/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200727_224457.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233349.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200725_233129.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="/Imagens/Filme/Screenshot_20200725_233110.jpg" class="Lápis" alt=""></div>
  </div>
```

My question is **how do I assign the values from `<option>` element to the `<img>` or `<div>`** in order t match them when I use JavaScript and change the display .

For example , If I want to give an img the year 2004. How do I assign it to a specific div/img ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the img's parent div data attributes. You will obviously want to use your own data in your own language.

`<div data-year="2014" data-size="xl" data-style="illustration"><img src="/Imagens/Screenshot_20200727_224457.jpg" alt=""></div>`

then have an event listener in javascript and set each value in an object for later using. Then simply hide ALL photos by default, then find matching images and show them.

```
    data = {};
    gallery = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery div");
    document.querySelector("select").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      data[e.target.getAttribute("id")] = e.target.value;
    
      gallery.forEach(function(div) { //sets them ALL as hidden first
        div.style.display = "none";
      });
    
      if (data["Ano"] != "" & data["Estilo"] != "" && data["Dimensões"] != "") {
        images = document.querySelector('[data-size='" + data["Dimensões"] + "'][data-style='" + data["Estilo"] + "'][data-size='" + data["Ano"] + "']')
      
    
      images.forEach(function(image) {
        image.style.display = "block";
      });
}
    
    });
```

Comment: Ok , thank you .

That's exactly what I needed ! The data attribute allows me to give the div a "criteria" and then use it on Javascript.

Cool =D

Answer (score 0):

Your image gallery has to be generated dynamically based on the selection(s).
If you can create an array of images with their corresponding attributes,  you can then iterate over them with the array's map() method and inject div elements with the image.